# If I force push into my remote repository, will it affect the main branch?

Tags: git

It’s my separate feature branch on our remote repository. I needed to delete a file so I force push my most recent change (deleting the file).

From my understanding; this doesn’t affect the main branch, since it’s just my branch. Just needed a confirmation?

Comment: Why would it? Can you elaborate a bit on why you might think changes in one branch would/should affect the other?

Comment: @esqew when I ran git log. It showed one commit from another dev on my team. But i think that was when I merged everyone’s branch in. So it kind of startled me, thinking main and mine would someone be tied together after all. But maybe not

Answer (score 3):

> From my understanding; this doesn’t effect the main branch, since it’s just my branch.

Force pushing one's branch would not affect other branches on the remote repository.
It would  only affect others working on the same feature branch, as they would need to reset their local branch to the new remote one.

But in your case, deleting a file should not involve a `git push --force`.

A simple `git rm -- aFile` + `git push` is enough.